# Optimal social cost = 1 ... Game Theory paper

Tags: game-theory

Say you have $n = m$ identical links, where each agent $i$ has a unit of traffic to push from source to sink, that is, $w_i = 1$.

I've seen it stated, but not shown, that the optimal solution has cost 1.

So why does the optimal solution have a cost of 1?

Full context:

Consider the case where there are n = m agents, each with unit trac, i.e., wi = 1.
It is easy to see that the set of uniform strategies with $p_i^j$ = 1/m, for i, j = 1 ... m is a Nash equilibrium. To compute the social cost of the equilibrium we see this as the problem
of throwing m balls into m bins. The social cost of the equilibrium is equal to the expected maximum number of balls in a bin which is well known to be (log m= log log m). Given that the optimal solution has cost 1, the lower bound follows.

....
Note: the cost is the expected maximum traffic over all edges.

Note: The bigger context is that we are trying to find a bound on the price of anarchy with 2 players. The part that I posted above is trying to show a lower bound. The price of anarchy is defined as the max(social cost/opt). To prove a lower bound, one of the things the authors showed was that the opt was 1. My question is how they arrived at it.

http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~elias/publications/paper-kp09.pdf
(See part right below theorem 1)

Edit: Social (or overall) optimum is defined as the sum of all delays over all agents.

Comment: Could you specify more explicitly the game that the agents are playing? Even under the "Full context" section it is not clear what are the nodes and actions available to the player at each node of the game. Neither is it clear what the payoffs, the definition of what you call "social cost", or the definition of optimality is.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Hints:** (hoping that I understand your problem correctly)

You assume $n=m$ and $w_i = 1$ for all $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

- Suppose that each individual choses a different link to send her traffic load $w_i$. Is this possible given your assumption?
- If it is possible, can you think of any "more optimal" way to convey the amount of traffic through the network, given that optimality is defined in terms of the delay endured by the sender?
- If not this situation is optimal right? Then what is the individual cost each sender is enduring in this situation (i.e. when each individual choses a different link to send her traffic load $w_i$)?

Comment: So it seems that we have the optimal solution is when the agents choose different edges to send their traffic. If that is correct, I can't tell if the authors just reweighted the $w_i$'s to get an opt of 1 or if the arithmetic works out s.t. the opt = 1.

Comment: The result does not hold without these assumptions. Try to construct a counter example with for instance $n=m$ but $w_k = 100$ for some $k\in N$. You should be able to see that the choice of optimal roads remains the same, but the cost is not 1 anymore. In the proof of the theorem you mention in the paper, it pretty clear that the authors intentionally make these assumption to deal with a simpler case. As to how they generalize afterward to other cases, I haven't looked into that.

Comment: if each $w_i$ = 1, then the opt = 1 because .5*1+.5*1 = 1?

Comment: Given your comment, maybe your puzzlement comes from a confusion between optimal total delay and optimal cost. In this case the optimal total delay would be $n$, but the optimal individual cost -- which is as I understand it what the authors talk about in the proof of theorem 1 -- equals 1. Does that help?

Comment: socially optimal refers to the overall optimal. It is as if you had benevolent dictator could guide everyone to reduce the overall cost. I had assumed that optimal solution = socially optimal, which I had thought meant optimal solution means optimal total delay.

Comment: So why did you interpret optimal solution as optimal individual cost?

Comment: I did not. I am not sure I understand your question. In the proof of theorem 1 it is said that "the optimal solution has cost 1". Nowhere in the paper do I see it stated that "the optimal solution = 1". This would not make sense has the optimal solution cannot be just a scalar. The optimal solution is an allocation of each individual's traffic amount to a particular link, so it should take the form of a vector ([1,6],[2,2],...,) where the first number in the brackets is the the index of an agent and the second is the link she is assigned to.

Comment: As I read your question again, I guess this might be the source of your confusion. In the title you ask "Why is the optimal social cost = 1" and in the body of the question you ask something different, namely "why does the optimal solution = 1?
" suggesting that you view "optimal solution" and "optimal social cost" as identical. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11481/discussion-between-martin-van-der-linden-and-user9915)

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. Also, it won't let me enter the chat.

Comment: Do my last comments solve your problem? You said that I understood you correctly which means that you viewed "optimal solution" and "optimal social cost" as identical. Do you see that they are different? Isn't it the source of your problem in understanding the paper?

Comment: So I'm still left with original question: how are they deriving 1 for the optimal social cost? Nor am I sure why I should interpret optimal social cost as optimal individual social cost?

Comment: Sorry, I have spend more time than I planned to trying to answer this question and I cannot provide a better explanation that the one I gave you in my former comment explaining why the optimal solution is a vector and the optimal cost a scalar... Yet this is really what you need to work on to solve your understanding problem. Hope you can eventually figure it out yourself, good luck! –

Comment: Look it's a massive assumption, and one that I'm not sure is warranted to say that the cost of the optimal solution is the same as optimal individual cost. Which is what you are saying in second comment.

Comment: I do think that when they write "the optimal solution has cost 1", they mean "the optimal solution has individual cost 1" mostly because it is the only way to make sense of their contention that this is equal to 1. Yet, this might be subject to interpretation. A good way to figure it out is to contact the authors themselves. I have done that in the past with econ/game theory articles (e.g. to solve this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376640/invariance-of-strategy-proof-social-choice-function-when-peaks-are-made-close-fr) and I have always receive nice and helpful answers.